Jacobi relation when multiplicities are present

Assume a triad involving the adjoint has multiplicity, e.g. $8\bigotimes 8=1+8+8'+\dots$ in the Lie algebra $SU_3$. How can I handle this in a graphic formalism? Is both $8$ and $8'$ the adjoint, so I just place multiplicity labels $888,888'$ on the dots in the image? Or do I also need a different "color" for $8$ and $8'$ since they are actually different irreps? Or are there even two kind of multiplicities that must be treated differently? (I've heard of "inner" and "outer".)

What is the source for the graphical notation you use? The notation may vary significantly between books.

@VladimirLysikov: My own, although using colored edges for irreps and colored vertices for multiplicity seems natural. (Point is, I've seen the first one over and over, but never the second.)
